# why cant i call a mutatable function in a button

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

I keep getting an error when I try to call my function on the button press. I am fairly new to swift so there might be an obvious mistake. The code here is what i have that should involve the error. I have searched for other answers to this but could not find anything. I dont know what i need to do to call a mutable function.

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView2: View {

@State public var weightLifted:Int
@State public var repsPerformed:Int
@State private var percentOfReps:Double = 0.0
@State private var oneRepMax:Double = 0.0

var weightAtEachPercent:Array = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

mutating func calcMax() {

    switch repsPerformed {
    case 1: percentOfReps = 1.0
    case 2: percentOfReps = 0.975
    case 3: percentOfReps = 0.95
    case 4: percentOfReps = 0.925
    case 5: percentOfReps = 0.9
    case 6: percentOfReps = 0.875
    case 7: percentOfReps = 0.85
    case 8: percentOfReps = 0.825
    case 9: percentOfReps = 0.8
    case 10: percentOfReps = 0.75
    case 11: percentOfReps = 0.725
    case 12: percentOfReps = 0.7125
    case 13: percentOfReps = 0.7
    case 14: percentOfReps = 0.685
    case 15: percentOfReps = 0.675
    default:
        percentOfReps = 0.5
    }
   oneRepMax = Double(weightLifted) / percentOfReps

    weightAtEachPercent[0] = oneRepMax
    weightAtEachPercent[1] = oneRepMax * 0.975
    weightAtEachPercent[2] = oneRepMax * 0.95
    weightAtEachPercent[3] = oneRepMax * 0.9
    weightAtEachPercent[4] = oneRepMax * 0.875
    weightAtEachPercent[5] = oneRepMax * 0.825
    weightAtEachPercent[6] = oneRepMax * 0.75
    weightAtEachPercent[7] = oneRepMax * 0.7125
    weightAtEachPercent[8] = oneRepMax * 0.675
}
var body: some View {

 Button(action: {
                //Place of error
                //I tried using self.calcMax() as well but same error
                //Error "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable 
                calcMax()
            }) {
                Text("Calculate")
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should format your code block better, because at this point it is very hard to read (due to the indentation). It will help people follow your process and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding @State to the array?

and remember that @State is always considered to be private, because when you use @State, you're essentially saying SwiftUI **owns** that view.

A better solution is to use an @Binding or an @ObservableObject/@ObservedObject instead.

A better quick read on it can be found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject):

Answer (score 0):

Views are immutable. They can store information in `@State` variables that will be copied over to new immutable instances, but the View itself can't change. So View functions can't be `mutating`.

Each piece of information should have a single source of truth. If this information is entirely internal to the view, and nothing outside the view needs to see it, then mark it `@State`. If things outside the view need it, but the view needs to be able to signal that it's changed, make it a `@Binding`. If it's a model that the view needs to react to, make it an `@ObservedObject`.

In your case, the updated values are already `@State`, and changing state doesn't actually change a view (it triggers the creation of a new view). So you can just remove the `mutating` modifier.